# How to convert a slice of hexadecimal bytes to integer

Tags: go

I'm converting a base 10 integer to a hexadecimal string before storing it in a file:

```
str := fmt.Sprintf("%08x", 1662489944)

b, _ := hex.DecodeString(str)

file.Write(b) //seems to write 63179558
```

Yes I know this probably looks silly and I have no doubt there's better ways to do this: I wanted to pad this value with leading 0's.

When I read the contents of the file, I get a slice of bytes:

```
[]byte{63, 17, 95, 58}
```

How do I convert this slice back into the base 10 value of 1662489944 (32 bit)?

Comment: Can you post the whole snippet? How did you write the string to file? Using `Write` or `WriteString`?

Comment: @Inian I might be missing something, but my example shows I'm using `file.Write` and so I'm exactly sure how to better answer your question.

I'm not going to post the 'whole snippet', in large part because it's spread out across multiple files with surrounding irrelevant code. I'm trying to distill the problem as simply as possible - that being said I revised it a bit.

Comment: Is the byte slice you obtained back represented in decimal or hex? It should be hex values i.e. 0x63 and not 63 (decimal)?

Comment: @Inian When I run hexdump on the file, it shows 63 17 95 58. When I read the file using what I imagine is a pretty standard approach

`b := make([]byte, size)
bSize, err := cs.file.Read(b)`

It seems to give me a slice of bytes like I showed in the example, at least how it's displayed when I use `fmt.Println`

Comment: `hexdump` is dumping bytes in hex, so its the latter, so `[]byte{0x63, 0x17, 0x95, 0x58}` is what you read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not quite clear, how your actual hex-string is written to the file and read back. But based on one your comment,

> When I run hexdump on the file, it shows `63 17 95 58`

Which is evident enough that the byte slice you should be dealing with, should be in hex notation and not in decimal, i.e. `[]byte{0x63, 0x17, 0x95, 0x58}` or in decimal byte slice `[]byte{99, 23, 149, 88}`, but definitely not the one posted in OP. This can be confirmed by couple of methods in `hex` package, that encode hex string to bytes and vice-versa,

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    const s = "63179558"
    decoded, err := hex.DecodeString(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", decoded)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", hex.EncodeToString([]byte{0x63, 0x17, 0x95, 0x58}))

}
```

which produces

```
[99 23 149 88]
63179558
```

confirming my above assumption.

As for your original question to convert the slice of hex bytes back to base 10, you could use the the [encoding/binary](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary) package's implementation of [ByteOrder](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#ByteOrder), to convert to 32-bit, 64-bit numbers. So quite simply just

```golang
binary.BigEndian.Uint32([]byte{0x63, 0x17, 0x95, 0x58})
```

[Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/SlEMkHl7IjU)

Answer (score 3):

The following code writes the value to the file as a four byte big endian number.

```
str := fmt.Sprintf("%08x", 1662489944)
b, _ := hex.DecodeString(str)
file.Write(b)
```

Use this code to reverse the transformation:

```
b = make([]byte, 4)
io.ReadFull(file, b)
n := int(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(b))
```

[PlayGround example](https://go.dev/play/p/o8iF25__l6t).

Here's a more direct way to write the number to the file as  a four byte big endian number.

```
b := make([]byte, 4)
binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(b, 1662489944)
file.Write(b)
```